# What happens to the old spell when a ranger replaces it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, ranger, character-advancement

I just need to figure out how this works. Since rangers don't write their spells down anywhere, what happens whenever I replace a spell that I gain from leveling? Is the spell just gone or am I able to swap between them whenever I have a long rest the same way other classes can?

Answer (score 27):

## The ranger can no longer cast replaced spells.

Rangers don't prepare specific spells from a larger set of known spells in the same way that some other classes do. Instead, like bards, they can always cast any of the spells they know, provided they have spell slots available.

This means that when a ranger chooses to replace one of the spells they know when they gain a level, they no longer know the old spell, and can't cast it at all. They can't change the spells they know again until they gain another level.